# Grub rescue, no XP option

Tags: 11.04

I tried to install Ubuntu on a pc for a friend that sometimes freezes up in windows XP. (My thinking was that if it freezes up in Ubuntu then it is a hardware problem.) Just nearly finished installing alongside XP and it froze up and had to push the button. I was unable to login to the Ubuntu installation, it did not show a proper login screen and was unresponsive. So then using UBCD4Windows i deleted the main big Ubuntu partition. One problem is that XP did not show up at all as a boot option after that failed Ubuntu installation attempt. If i could get into XP again perhaps i could delete the Ubuntu partitions? 
Also have a big XP problem because i replaced a dead Motherboard and made rescue DVDs but they wont work unless Motherboard is tattooed.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the Ubuntu partition will solve nothing by itself, it will only make things worse.

Use a Windows XP CD to boot. If you don't have yours, any Windows XP installation CD should do the trick.

Then, when asked, press R to enter the recovery console.

Issue this commands:

```
fixmbr
```

And that's it, Windows should boot again. Now, you can delete the Ubuntu partition and try again if you want to.

Comment: Sorry, it is a HP pc with Windows XP Media Center edition so can i use an XP cd to fix the MBR? 
I am getting a caution message after i typed: "fixmbr": 

**caution**
This computer appears to have a non-standard or invalid master boot record.
FIXMBR may damage your partition tables if you proceed.
This could cause all the partitions on the current hard disk to become
inaccesible.
If you are not having problems accessing your drive to not continue.
Are you sure you want to write a new MBR?

Comment: Just answer yes. If something goes wrong, there's still hope so don't worry.

Comment: Gosh, it says the partitions will be inaccessible? Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I tried that and got another error message. Disk read error,,,

Comment: At boot time or when you made the fixmbr? Boot with a Ubuntu CD or pendrive. Don't install it, go to the live environment. Then, open the Disks tool on the dash. If you can identify the Windows XP partition, mount and try accessing it. Is the data there? If not, we'll have to recover the partition table.